# Export CAD .STEP files format with Mathematica?

Tags: export

This question is related to following question: [questions/130883](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130883/is-it-possible-to-create-stp-3d-model-from-graphics3d) which has not been answered yet, because a workaround has been found using an import feature from Autocad.

Basically, I want to generate a 3D object or 3D curve by Mathematica and import it in .step format in a CAD software (SolidEdge). An stl format is not enough to do what I need because I need to import the 3D object into a native CAD design while keeping the geometry relationship.

In other terms, I have a 3D CAD design in SolidEdge, I export it as stl file, then I import it to Mathematica, do some processing (like slicing it by a plane or another surface, drawing geodesics,etc.) , after that I need to export the resulting 3D curve into a step file, in order to reimport it in my initial CAD design in SolidEdge, then finish the design into Solidedge.

I had a look on Mathematica CAD format Export list  from documentation, as well as the import format file for SolidEdge, and there is no other match than stl, which is not what I want.

Any Hints?

Comment: DXF format does not work? Seemingly, both _Mathematica_ and _SolidEdge_ can handle it (see [here](https://www.solid-system-team.de/cad-cam/solid-edge/funktionen/schnittstellen/); unfortunately the page is in German, but that should not matter). My first guess would have been OBJ, but apparently, _SolidEdge_ does not support it (honestly?! Oo).

Comment: STEP, SAT, and IGES are the dominant standards for this type of 3D CAD interchange. It would be nice if Mathematica would support at least one of them, preferable STEP. STL is useless for anything other than pretty pictures and 3D priniting.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, thanks for the link, I'll try to get it translated.We tried with DXF 3D but the test design were rendered all flat ! OBJ was not in the import list, but we continue the tests.

Comment: @David Keith- I fully agree BTW it is apparently the same situation with MATLAB

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, I read the link (thanks google translate) but you were right it is understandable even with my poor German. It looks like the same import format list I found into SolidEdge interface. Thanks.

Comment: Yes possibly, I have to have a look on this. Thanks for sharing the info!