# Export Discretized ImplicitRegion as step using OpenCascade

Tags: export, finite-element-method, regions, mesh, opencascade

Following the reply by @user21 to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130883/is-it-possible-to-create-stp-3d-model-from-graphics3d) on exporting a region to a step file, I tried to do the same for a Discretized ImplicitRegion, but OpenCascadeShape didn't appear to work. Is there a switch or a constraint I need to apply to Discretized regions to allow OpenCascadeShape to handle them?

```
imReg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 - z < 0, {x, y, z}];
discReg = DiscretizeRegion[imReg, {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 5}}]
```

[image: discReg]

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
shape = OpenCascadeShape[discReg]
```

[image: output]

```
OpenCascadeShapeExport["~/shape.step", shape]
```

[image: export output]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `ToBoundaryMesh` like so:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
imReg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 - z < 0, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 5}}];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[imReg];
bmesh["Wireframe"]
shape = OpenCascadeShape[bmesh]
OpenCascadeShapeExport["~/shape.stp", shape]
```

The shape can now be read in by external packages such as SolidWorks.

[image]

Comment: Didn't realize you can specify the limits in ImplicitRegion along with the variables i.e. {{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},{z,0,5}} rather than {x,y,z}   (I don't see that in the manual, or maybe it is just Implicit :-)    That saves me having to explicitly Discretize it too.